# Can you use a custom number set in one place only to be the font size used in storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to set the font size in storyboard using a custom number.

I want to achieve the exact same thing like adding a color into assets with new ColorSet and then using this in the storyboard. I want this because if at some point in time I want to change sizes, I will only have to change the original number in one place only and everything gets updated automagically.

PS: I know you can do this in code... but then again you have to set the font size in every single screen for every single item.

Comment: The appearance protocol allows control over all instances of a UI class  (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance)

Answer (score 0):

> I know you can do this in code... but then again you have to set the font size in every single screen for every single item.

Basically this is what dynamic type is for. Surrender control and give up your hard coding of values and let the *user* decide the sizes. All you have to do is respond, which can be automatic.

Comment: I was hoping there was something else I could use. Allowing the user to change the font sizes isn't something intended for every custom app.

I want to achieve something else here.
Let's say I have 3 values:
SmallFont = 15
MediumFont = 17
LargeFont = 20

I want to use these values in storyboard, but by the name, not the values. And the only changes that would be made on these would be if the client decides so or if there is a redesign in the user interface. But I'm now assuming there is no way to achieve this from storyboard.